# Can Chromium Embedded Framework's MediaRecorder support h.264 MIME types?

Tags: google-chrome, h.264, chromium-embedded, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I've been using the commercial Google Chrome to do some `window.MediaRecorder` stuff with h.264 (aka avc1).

To see whether that works I use

```
const ok = window.MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm; codecs="avc1.42E01E"')
```

On the commercial browser this returns `true`, but on CEF it returns `false`. Is there a way around this?

I guess the h.264 / avc1 support is something Google adds when they do their commercial build of the browser. But, there are other command-line arguments that enable features for launching CEF. I wonder if there's one for this.

Comment: No, there's no command line argument. Support is compiled into the build, there's a discussion at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13515 h264 and AAC require licences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can support H.264, but you need to build it with the proprietary codes feature enabled.

Follow [these directions](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart.md) and use this value for `GN_DEFINES`.

```
set GN_DEFINES=proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
```

More to come.